# Charge script on android

Tags: android, boot

this is my first question here but i've used stackoverflow for years now.
In the last 2 days i've searched a lot about the "charge" script on google but with no sucess. All I whant is my tablet automatically boot on charger connected but it does not seem as easy as it first seamed...

If someone knows how to do this it would be great, I'm not using a Samsung tablet, i'm using a WM8880MID tablet. The intention is to use the tab as a "console".

(Quite a bad EN, I'm sorry)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. You will have to add additional hardware to do what you want